# Player collides with every tile's edge and gets stuck

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have a player character with rigidbody 2d component and a box collider. when I enter playmode and try to move my player gets stuck on the edges of tiles under it and stops moving,
what have I done wrong and what are some solutions?

Comment: Can you provide us with some script?
Your Question is too broad..

Comment: There's a million things that could be going wrong ranging from scripts to esoteric physics settings. Try adding more information to your question so we can try to reproduce it. Screenshots, scripts, anything that you think might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about your collider hitting caught on the inside edge of tiles, you're running into a problem known as [Ghost Vertices](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/ghost-vertices). This happens when you happen to hit an internal edge of a collider, for example:

[image: Ghost Verticies example]

If you happen to be using a [TilemapCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TilemapCollider2D.html) (I assume you are, since you said "tiles"), you can add a [CompositeCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CompositeCollider2D.html) and enable the tilemap collider's `Used by Composite` bool. This will combine the colliders of every individual tile into one big collider, removing any internal edges, and resolving your problem.